# how can i find a json file in the website

Tags: json, web-scraping, hyperlink, xml-namespaces, scrape

supposedly, there should be a json file in this tag. But I can't see where it is.

in the website, there is download link to download json file. but in this tag, i couldn't tell how it works.

```
<a role="button" tabindex="0"><svg fill="currentColor" height="10" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="0" viewbox="0 0 512 512" width="10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M216 0h80c13.3 0 24 10.7 24 24v168h87.7c17.8 0 26.7 21.5 14.1 34.1L269.7 378.3c-7.5 7.5-19.8 7.5-27.3 0L90.1 226.1c-12.6-12.6-3.7-34.1 14.1-34.1H192V24c0-13.3 10.7-24 24-24zm296 376v112c0 13.3-10.7 24-24 24H24c-13.3 0-24-10.7-24-24V376c0-13.3 10.7-24 24-24h146.7l49 49c20.1 20.1 52.5 20.1 72.6 0l49-49H488c13.3 0 24 10.7 24 24zm-124 88c0-11-9-20-20-20s-20 9-20 20 9 20 20 20 20-9 20-20zm64 0c0-11-9-20-20-20s-20 9-20 20 9 20 20 20 20-9 20-20z"></path></svg> JSON</a>
```

I thought the json data might be in the xmlns, but when I open it, it just says it's mutable.

I am very new to this and don't know what to do next.

Comment: there must be something in the javscript code which downloads the json, this just looks like a button with a svg picture.

Comment: "https://worldpopulationreview.com/country-rankings/pollution-by-country"  I was trying to get the last table through either json file or from the web directly. but I can't find the json file, I can't get the table either through BS4

Comment: it seems to be an odd way to do the button, the code must be in the javascript event on the `a` element which encompasses both buttons. However, it seems the csv data is actually in the `href` attribute as a blob, so I would just get that, and then you can convert that to JSON if you want :))

Comment: but the most confusing part for me is that, in the inspection mode, I can clearly see there are three tables in the URL. but when I use BS4 parse it, it can only find two tables. The last one is missing. where should I go further?

Comment: I have no idea, I haven't used BS4. But maybe you can edit the question (add the link and some more details) and maybe someone else can help. And add bs4 as a tag maybe

Comment: Thank you. I figured the question out. The result is, there is no Json file in that download link. but If I scrape the website, the json file shows as a string in the body. so I just take that string out and name it the Json file. then I can operate it as a normal Json file.

Comment: cool why don't you answer your own question and accept that to close the question :))